# comments in multilingual support

Tags: multilingual

I am making a website application to support factory automation, which will have users from various countries knowing different languages. I have internationalized all the string in the website so it is understandable by all users. However users have to write comments on the website related to factory operations, which they will write in their own language and it may not be understandable by users in other countries.

I wanted to know what are the best practices to help with this scenario.

One way I was thinking to not let users write comments- rather I provide possibilities of comments in a drop down which they can select. And I can internationalize those possibilities. But this is not an elegant solution, since the 'possible comments' may not be comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a solid no-fail solution available for this kind of problem, but here are some possibilities:

- Leverage a translation engine and computer-translate the comments. How well this works depends on the engine used and the language, but it gives the reader a gist of the meaning. This solution loses a lot of use when there are a lot of technical or proprietary terms used. A lot of international webshops actually use this technique.
- Encourage your users to post comments in a common language, or a language that most of your users will know, like English, Chinese of Spanish, depending on your markets.
- Employ translators to regularly translate essential comments

The solution you mentioned is also pretty decent when the possible text is limited, otherwise it will spin out of control very fast.